# Cannot find boost/asio/io_context.hpp when compiling with g++-8

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, ubuntu-18.04

I am on Ubuntu 18.04, the g++-8 compiler is unable to find the libboost-asio module. However, I installed libboost with

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Whenever I try to compile with the following header include

```
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
```

I get thrown with a compiler error saying the header file cannot be located.

```
fatal error: boost/asio/io_context.hpp: No such file or directory #include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
```

I am able to compile with other boost headers i.e boost/array.hpp but not with asio.

Running a version check on libbooost

```
dpkg -s libboost-all-dev | grep 'Version'
```

returns : Version: 1.65.1.0ubuntu1

I am also unable to find any trace of asio using aptitude. I suspect it is not installed together with the apt-get command. How should I approach this ?

## Update 1

I found that the boost/asio libraries are installed under /usr/lib/boost/asio.
I then tried the following command to compile, still gets the same error.

```
g++-8 -I/usr/include/boost/asio -o run foo.cpp
```

Comment: Check if the boost include directories are included in your path, otherwise pass it with the ``-I<path>` flat to your compiler.

Comment: I see that the boost/asio libs are installed at /usr/include/boost/asio, but even with the -I/usr/include/boost/asio I still get the same error. Am I missing something out ?

Comment: I think you have to include the boost root directory, i.e. `-I/usr/include/boost`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to someone pointing out to me that io_context is only available past boost 1.66, I am now able to compile after building boost 1.66 from official sources.

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg -l libboost-all-dev` identifies version 1.65.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 ("bionic"). In the boost.org website, this version uses [`boost::asio::io_service.hpp`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer1.html).

Minimal working example (`timer1.cpp`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
    t.wait();
    std::cout  << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with `g++ -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -g timer1.cpp -lboost_system -o timer1` after doing `sudo apt install libboost-dev-all g++`.